# Will an FPGA be useful here?

Tags: optimization, fpga

I'm writing some code for a piece of network middleware. Right now, our code is running too slowly.

We've already done one round of rewrites and optimizations, but we seem to be running into hard limitations on what can be done in software.

The slowness of the code stems from one subroutine - an esoteric sampling algorithm from computational statistics. Because the math involved is somewhat similar to the stuff done in DSP, I'm wondering if we can use an FPGA to accelerate the computation.

My question is basically in the title - how do I tell whether an FPGA (or even ASIC) will give a useful speedup in my use case?

EDIT: A 'useful' speedup is one that is significant enough to justify the cost and dev time required to build the FPGA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is to have an experienced FPGA engineer look at the algorithm and tell you what it would take in development time and bill of material cost for a solution.

Without knowing the details of your algorithm it is harder to guess.  How parallelizable is the problem?  Or can it be heavily pipelined?  How many multiply/accumulate/dsp operations are required?  Can you approximate some calculations with a big look up table or other FPGA dsp techniques (CORDIC).  FPGAs can do many, many more of these operations in parallel (every clock cycle) 100s or even 1000s depending on how much you are willing to spend on an FPGA.  Without knowing the details and having an experienced FPGA/DSP engineer look at the problem it is going to be hard to get a real feel though.

Some other options are:

- look into DSP chips (TI dsp chips are one example).
- Does your processor have SIMD instructions available that are not being used?